# Google Calendar API - Clear all events

Tags: google-calendar-api, google-api-client

I'm trying to clear all the events of a google calendar using the calendar ID.

https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/calendar/v3/python/latest/calendar_v3.calendars.html#clear

Attempting it, gives a "400 Bad Request" response from either Python or a simple curl call using the Google API Explorer:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "invalid",
    "message": "Invalid Value"
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "Invalid Value"
 }
}
```

From either the API explorer or the python API I'm providing only the calendar ID of the corresponding (non-primary) calendar I want to delete.

In Python:

```
service.calendars().clear(calendarId=<calid-found-in-calendarList().list()>).execute()
```

Which returns:

```
<HttpError 400 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/<calendar-id>4%40group.calendar.google.com/clear? returned "Invalid Value". Details: "[{'domain': 'global', 'reason': 'invalid', 'message': 'Invalid Value'}]">
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Hello there, can you confirm that the `calendarId` you are passing is a valid one? Are you able to execute the same request from the "Try this API" tool [here](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/calendars/clear)?

Comment: Hi @ale13,

I've already tried using the tool you mentioned.
I'm passing a valid calendar ID, as returned by the call to service.calendarList().list.

If I pass a non-valid ID (e.g. by changing a few letters of a valid one) I'm getting a "404 Not Found"

Comment: Is this your personal calendar? Or what kind of calendar are you trying to clear?

Comment: This is a personal but my primary calendar.

Comment: Did you end up reporting this behavior on Google's Issue Tracker in the end? Moreover, what kind of settings do you have set for this calendar?

Answer (score 0):

When I had tested the clear method of Calendars in Calendar API v3 before, I had experienced the same situation with you. When I used the value of `primary`, no error occurs. All events of the primary calendar are deleted. But, when I used the calendar ID except for the primary calendar, the same issue occurred.

When I saw [the official document](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/calendars/clear), it says `Clears a primary calendar. This operation deletes all events associated with the primary calendar of an account.`. But about `calendarId` in this method, it also says `Calendar identifier. To retrieve calendar IDs call the calendarList.list method. If you want to access the primary calendar of the currently logged in user, use the "primary" keyword.`.

These documents consuse me. So, I checked this "clear" method at Discovery API. [Ref](https://calendar-json.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest?version=v3) It says as follows.

```
"clear": {
  "parameters": {
    "calendarId": {
      "location": "path",
      "required": true,
      "type": "string",
      "description": "Calendar identifier. To retrieve calendar IDs call the calendarList.list method. If you want to access the primary calendar of the currently logged in user, use the \"primary\" keyword."
    }
  },
  "scopes": [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar"
  ],
  "httpMethod": "POST",
  "id": "calendar.calendars.clear",
  "description": "Clears a primary calendar. This operation deletes all events associated with the primary calendar of an account.",
  "parameterOrder": [
    "calendarId"
  ],
  "path": "calendars/{calendarId}/clear"
},
```

From above document, I thought that the calendar ID can be retrieved by the calendarList.list method. But, this "clear" method might not be able to be used for the calendar except for the primary calendar.

And, when I saw the error message, when the calendar ID like `###@group.calendar.google.com` is used, the error of `"message": "Invalid Value"` occurs. But, when `sample` is used as the calendar ID, `"message": "Not Found"` is returned. It seems that the API might search the calendar. In this case, even when the URL encoding is used, the same issue occurs. From this situation, I thought that this might be a bug.

But, I'm not sure whether this is the current specification or a bug. So, I searched this situation at the issue tracker. But, unfortunately, I couldn't find the same issue. So how about reporting this at the Google issue tracker? [Ref](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker)

#### Reference:

- [Calendars: clear](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/calendars/clear)

Comment: Thanks @Tanaike,

I might as well create the issue :)

Comment: @bergercookie Thank you for replying. Also, I would like to recommend reporting it. I apologize that I cannot directly resolve your issue.

Comment: Hi @Tanaike, I still have the same issue (it's Feb 2020 now). Did you find a workaround or anything? Maybe I need to try to fetch all events in a secondary calendar and delete them in batch, need to check the doc if possible.

Comment: @Evgeny In the current stage, it seems that this issue has still not resolved. I deeply apologize for this. As the current workaround, how about retrieving all event IDs and delete them?

Comment: @Tanaike I tried it, but the API has rate limiting and I need to support exponential calls, it will take ages to delete all events.

Comment: @Evgeny Thank you for replying. About `I tried it, but the API has rate limiting and I need to support exponential calls, it will take ages to delete all events.`, this issue is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for my poor skill. I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor skill. By the way, can you provide your script of `I tried it`?

Answer (score 0):

Something to add to this when I encountered the same issue. Seeing that clearing secondary calendars of events is not currently an option, you can outright delete the calendar and re-create it however, the downside to this is the change in the calendar id on re-creation.

Delete calendar [documentation](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/calendars/delete)

> Deletes a secondary calendar. Use calendars.clear for clearing all events on primary calendars.